# How to create new rows with missing years and populate them with current rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
overflow_data={'state': ['CA', 'CA', 'HI', 'HI', 'HI', 'NY', 'NY'], 
'year':  [2010, 2013, 2010, 2012, 2016, 2009, 2013],
'value':  [1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 5]}
pd.DataFrame(overflow_data)
```

Starting DataFrame:

[image: Starting DataFrame]

I would like to fill in the missing years for each state, and use the prior year's values for those years, so the table would look like this:

Expected output:

[image: How the DataFrame should look]

Comment: much better if you shared data, instead of pics. and kindly avoid redirection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for `pivot` and fill:

```
(df.pivot('year','state','value')   # you can print this line alone to see what it does
   .ffill().bfill()                 # fill missing the data based on the states
   .unstack()                       # transform back to original form
   .reset_index(name='value')
)
```

Output:

```
   state  year  value
0     CA  2009    1.0
1     CA  2010    1.0
2     CA  2012    1.0
3     CA  2013    3.0
4     CA  2016    3.0
5     HI  2009    1.0
6     HI  2010    1.0
7     HI  2012    2.0
8     HI  2013    2.0
9     HI  2016    3.0
10    NY  2009    2.0
11    NY  2010    2.0
12    NY  2012    2.0
13    NY  2013    5.0
14    NY  2016    5.0
```

---

**Note** I just realized that the above is slightly different than what you are asking for. It only spawns data to **all available years** in the data, not resamples the data for the continuous years.

For what you ask, we can resolve to `reindex` with groupby:

```
(df.set_index('year').groupby('state')
   .apply(lambda x: x.reindex(np.arange(x.index.min(), x.index.max()+1)).ffill())
   .reset_index('state',drop=True)
   .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
    year state  value
0   2010    CA    1.0
1   2011    CA    1.0
2   2012    CA    1.0
3   2013    CA    3.0
4   2010    HI    1.0
5   2011    HI    1.0
6   2012    HI    2.0
7   2013    HI    2.0
8   2014    HI    2.0
9   2015    HI    2.0
10  2016    HI    3.0
11  2009    NY    2.0
12  2010    NY    2.0
13  2011    NY    2.0
14  2012    NY    2.0
15  2013    NY    5.0
```

Comment: Wow, this is very cool. Doing the apply while reindexing and limiting the values within min & max. I was trying to look at other ways to do it. Concise. Thx